# Create a large number of entities in Breezejs

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, breeze

I have a scenario on the UI where a user has three set of values presented in  dropdowns (50+ possible values). The user needs to create all possible permutations based on these set of values in a single action. In the background, each permutation translates to an entity that is created through breezejs using `manager.createEntity`. With a large number of possible permutation (50*50*50) the process to create all the entities and eventually save them, is extremely slow to a point that the browser freezes.

The user should be able to manipulate all possible permutations before deciding to save the final result or even cancel the whole process.

I tried to create all entities on the server without persisting them to the database and then load them back but that creates a whole new challenge in itself. Breezejs has no way to treat these entities as new ones (Not yet persisted to the database). And even if there is a way, we still need to manage entities keys to prevent the different entity from colliding in the cache.

Is there a way to have a work around this issue. I cannot persist the temporary data until the user saves the whole parent context.

Below is a visual example of what a final result would look like. These permutations were created automatically for the user when he clicks on a generate button. You notice also that there is a drop down to allow the user to edit values. While that makes the page load slower because of all the html in the dom, it is not the bottleneck. The real one is the repetitive call to `manager.createEntity`

[image]

Comment: can you add a plunkr with a demo? did you profile the app to see where the bottleneck is ?

Comment: The bottleneck is manager.createEntity. It gets worse when your entity is composed of other entities that in their turn need a call to manager.createEntity. I sadly cannot setup an example on plunkr, it's quite a complex piece, i'm going to attach a screen shot to the question to highlight the issue though

Comment: I doube breeze was built to handle something like this. You'll have to rethink your approach, probably without breeze